# If graph has cross edge, whether it is singly connected or not

Tags: algorithm

when I look "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd", encounter this question below.

22.3-13 *
A directed graph G is singly connected if u -> v implies that G contains
at most one simple path from u to v for all vertices V . Give an efficient
algorithm to determine whether or not a directed graph is singly connected.

some of answer like that "run DFS once from each vertex. The graph is singly connected if and only if there are no forward edges and there are no cross edges"

but I doubt this situation. Example, if all edges of graph (A->D, D->E, E->A, B->C, C->A), DFS begin at A, therefore C->A is cross edge, but I think this graph is singly connected.
sorry, I can't upload a picture because permission of stackoverflow.

Comment: Your example graph has a circle, there is no way it is singly connected.

Comment: you can include a link to a img upload website

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski I design that graph, so it is't on website.

Comment: @kutschkem why a circle in graph, it is not singly connected?

Comment: @Bran Chiu with a circle, there are infinite paths between two nodes on the circle

Comment: @kutschkem circle should allow in "singly connected" i think.           u, v in circle for this concept count only once.

Comment: Look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytree

Comment: @kutschkem I still don't get it. polytrees is singly connected networks. but singly connected may not be polytree. So if as your method, could you give me the algorithm above in question 22.3-13?

Comment: Run DFS from every vertex, check if you encounter a node twice during any run (which would mean there are two paths from the start node to that node). If you really want to allow circles, you can exclude the start node from that rule (but i still think a circle is not singly connected)

Comment: @kutschkem thanks :) I will think over it

Answer (score 0):

There may  be cross edges in the graph, there may be cycle too and graph will be single connected(SC).
if we have forward edge it is clear that we have 2 paths to the destination V.
but in this condition if we have cross edge graph is not SC::
assume ab or zb is our cross edge in the graph, if there is a path between a and z graph is not SC,and if we do not have the same path it is absolutely SC. 
It is if ab(or zb) is our cross edge there should not be path(s) between a and z.